# Trouble using tuple<sf::Texture, bool> in a C++ header file

Tags: c++, sfml

### The Problem Code

I have the following function in my `functions.cpp` file:

```
tuple<sf::Texture, bool> load_texture(string texture_path){
    bool success = true;
    sf::Texture texture;
    if (!texture.loadFromFile(texture_path)){
        cout << "Texture failed to load" << endl;
        success = false;
    }
    return make_tuple(texture, success);
}
```

I am using this with the SFML 2.1 package so that you understand what `sf::Texture` is in reference to.

I'm trying to do a forward definition of this function in my `header.h` file like so:

```
tuple<sf::Texture, bool> load_texture(string texture_path);
```

But I get the following errors:

- Error 1: `syntax error : missing ';' before '<'`
- Error 2: `missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`
- Error 3: `'sf' : is not a class or namespace name`

I apologize if this is absurdly simple but I'm new to the header game.

### My question

What do I need to include in my header file to use the tuples and what do I need to include so that the compiler understands my reference to `sf::`? Should I be including `"SFML\Graphics.hpp"`?

If you need more information or code simply let me know.

Comment: _"Should I be including "SFML\Graphics.hpp"?"_ Did you try so? Did it help?

Comment: `#include <tuple>` and `std::tuple` (don't use namespaces in headers!)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I include it in my `functions.cpp`, should it be included in `header.h`?

Comment: A good [reference on `std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) might be a good start. Also the [SFML API reference](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/) might be a good read too.

Comment: @NickChapman I think so, as you're using it there, and actually cannot forward declare `sf::Texture` to be used with the tuple.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I just moved all `#include`s into `header.h` and this didn't improve the situation. Can you elaborate on not forward declaring `sf::Texture`?

Comment: @NickChapman _"Can you elaborate ..."_ Your declaration uses `tuple<sf::Texture, bool>` as return type. The tuple instantiation needs to see the full declaration of `sf::Texture` at this point. Unless you have something like `tuple<sf::Texture*, bool>` a forward declaration of `sf::Texture` won't suffice.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, ok that makes a lot of sense. I don't want to waste your time so can you link me to a resource on what kind of definition I want to use if a forward definition won't work.

Comment: @NickChapman Looks like you'll need to [`#include <Texture.hpp>`](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Texture.php) in `header.h` in particular.

Comment: Since you're only storing two elements in the tuple, it's probably more appropriate that you use [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).

Answer (score 1):

> *"I'm trying to do a forward definition of this function in my header.h file like so:"*

```
tuple<sf::Texture, bool> load_texture(string texture_path);
```

That's not really what makes up a forward declaration, but just a simple *function declaration*.

The problem indicated by the compiler errors merely says you're missing a complete declaration for the `sf::Texture` class at that point in the declaration.

To get around this, you need to [`#include <Texture.hpp>`](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Texture.php) in your `header.h` file. Also you'll need to [`#include <tuple>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/tuple) of course.

---

**header.h**

```
#if !defined(HEADER_H__)
#define HEADER_H__
#include <Texture.hpp>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

std::tuple<sf::Texture, bool> load_texture(std::string texture_path);
#endif // HEADER_H__
```

---

**functions.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

std::tuple<sf::Texture, bool> load_texture(std::string texture_path) {
    bool success = true;
    sf::Texture texture;
    if (!texture.loadFromFile(texture_path)) {
        cout << "Texture failed to load" << endl;
        success = false;
    }
    return make_tuple(texture, success);
}
```